# Script to detect OS architecture and select file-x32 or file-x64 based on result

Tags: linux, architecture, x86, 64-bit, detect

I am trying to make my script check for x32 or x64 OS and select files from the script package based on the results.

For example:
If the OS is x32-bit I want the script to copy file-x32 to the install directory
If the OS is x64-bit I want the script to copy file-x64 to the install directory

I came across this code which prints the result:

```
    if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` = "64" ]
    then
        echo "I'm 64-bit"
    else
        echo "I'm 32-bit"
    fi
```

Would it be as simple as to modify this script like this to do the job:

```
    if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` = "64" ]
    then
        mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x64 /var/destination
    else
        mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x32 /var/destination
    fi
```

If possible I would also like to echo to the user either:
x32-bit OS Detected
or
x64-bit OS Detected

Comment: WHy won't you just try that solution?

Comment: I did try that solution and yes it works but I was not sure if this was the correct method and also I would like to echo to the user which OS was detected..  I was also worried that some people install ubuntu x64 on a x32 system, could this fool the above script or does `getconf LONG_BIT` check the actual processor

Comment: I really am struggling to find a question there. If you want to know whether you can squeeze an echo there - go and try. If you worry about some scenarios then verify them and then work on solution.

Comment: So what you are actually saying is that there is really no need for this site as everything should be trial and error?  Just because something that I do works it does not mean it is the correct way to do it.  I am new to linux and I want to start off doing things correctly, that is why I asked for advice.  And since you are "really struggling to find a question there" I will copy clip it back down for you..  (does getconf LONG_BIT check the actual processor)..  If you can not or will not help, please do not bother leaving useless comments Puciek

Comment: Those are not useless comments, and you will find that people here jump on trivial questions, like this one, en mase while this one is pretty much empty. It's because your question is unclear. There is a great guide on asking questions http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

You can also see how the question you've added in the comment is not actually in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if-else block can contain multiple statements. Thus, if you want an echo for each branch, you could do something like so.

```
if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` = "64" ]
then
    echo "I'm 64-bit"
    mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x64 /var/destination
else
    echo "I'm 32-bit"
    mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x32 /var/destination
fi
```

If you would like to use the architecture information elsewhere, you can store it in a variable and do something like this:

```
arch=$(getconf LONG_BIT)
echo "I'm $arch-bit"
if [ "$arch" = "64" ]
then
    mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x64 /var/destination
else
    mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x32 /var/destination
fi
```

Even better, with the variable in place you can do this:

```
arch=$(getconf LONG_BIT)
echo "I'm $arch-bit"
mv /tmp/autoscript/file-x$arch /var/destination
```

Comment: That is brilliant Aaron, The last variable example would be best suited to my needs..  Thank you very much for your time..